# Build Javascript Variable Using jquery Manipulation

Tags: jquery, string, variables

I need to build a string variable using jQuery to find all the text nodes surrounded by span tags. Importantly I need to separate each segment of text with the pipe character "|".

For example take the following html:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<span>this</span> <span>is</span> <span>the</span> <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Using jQuery I need to produce the following:

```
var my_variable = "this|is|the|text";
```

So far I have the following jQuery statement but this just adds the pipe character at the end and doesn't separate each segment of text.

`var my_variable = $("#myDiv").find("span").text() + '|'`;

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Note: To remove the last pipe character at the end of the string I was going to use:

```
my_new_variable = "my_variable.slice(0, -1)";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) on the element of spans to get the text. Javascript arrays have a [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Join) method that will put the pipes between them but first you need to convert your jQuery object into a Javascript array. Use [`$.makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) for this.

```
var my_variable = $.makeArray($("#myDiv span").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
})).join("|");
```

Comment: I get the following error:

TypeError: Result of expression '$("#myDiv").find("span").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).join' [undefined] is not a function.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply - very close except I get a double "|" between each text string.

Comment: @hayler: when i run it i get `this|is|the|text`. I see no double pipes.

Comment: Yup, my bad.... I had a number of empty spans... Thanks very much for the super quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = [];
$('#myDiv span').each(function(){
    strings.push($(this).text());
});
var my_variable = strings.join('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pipeText="";

$('#myDiv span').each(function(){
  pipeText+=$(this).text() + "|";
});

pipeText = pipeText.slice(0, -1);
```